# Count elements in nested list

Tags: python, list, count, mapping, nested

The following python code should make it clear what i'd like to accomplish.

```
# Say I have the following list and I want to keep count of 1's while going through each nested list
L = [[1,1,0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]

# So I'd like to get a list containing [3, 5, 6, 12]
# I tried to find a compact way of doing this by mapping this list into a another list like such 
T = [L[:i].count(1) for i in range(len(L))]
# >>> [0, 0, 0, 0]


# But this doesn't work so how to count occurances for nested lists?
# Is there a compact way of doing this (maybe with Lambda functions)?

# I'd like to avoid using a function like:
def Nested_Count():
    Result = []
    count = 0
    for i in L:
        count += i.count(1)
        Result.append(count)
    return Result
# >>> [3, 5, 6, 12]
```

Please let me know if it's possible or not to have a more compact code to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[sum([x.count(1) for x in L[:i]]) for i in range(1, len(L) + 1)]
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sum` and a list comprehension.

```
L = [[1,1,0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
L2 = [sum(x) for x in L]
T = [sum(L2[:x+1]) for x in xrange(len(L2))]
```